# Adicionar vários telefones em um telephone_field no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou fazendo um cadastro de clientes aqui para loja e acontece que alguns clientes tem mais de 2 números de telefones o sistema já funciona com dois campos de telefone um fixo e um celular :

```
<%= f.label :telcelular , "Tel. Celular" %>
<%= f.telephone_field :telcelular %>

<%= f.label :telfixo , "Tel. Fixo" %>
<%= f.telephone_field :telfixo %>
```

Não há como eu criar um campo para cada telefone, já que não sei a quantidade de números de telefone que cada cliente possui, há alguma possibilidade de salvar todos os telefones somente em um campo?

Comment: O mais correto seria criar uma tabela `telefones` que contém uma referência para cliente (`cliente_id`). Você pode por tudo em um formulário usando Nested Attributes ([1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) [2](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) [3](http://highaltitudehacking.wordpress.com/2009/11/10/getting-the-right-html-for-rails-nested-model-forms/)), mas eu nunca tentei usar isso. O mais fáicl é criar um formulário separado só para adicionar os telefones.

Comment: Usando Nested Attributes fica fácil de fazer. E tem como deixar no formulário um botão para ir adicionando campos para telefones caso seja necessário. Pode dar uma olhada nesse exemplo http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão que não iria afetar muito o que já existe seria serializar esses campos. O postgress por exemplo permite que você armazene nele um array, e o Rails possui funções para serializar esse array.

O único problema acredito seria serializar os objetos que já estão no banco. No mais assim você poderia ter quantos telefones quiser em um campo só. Bastaria uma mudanças no modelo, controlador e um Javascript para imprimir mais campos na view...